# How to run x64 asp.net webpages on windows server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm getting assembly error while loading my asp.net page on windows server 2012. It's x64 builded. That's the reason, why i'm getting this error.

I think, there should be some settings in IIS, to give webpages x64 support.

Do you have any solution for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deactivated the 32-Bit in IIS. It was the solution..

**IIS -> Application Pool -> (website) -> Advanced Settings -> 32-Bit : false**

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this [IIS Compatibility](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45)

Comment: Yes, i checked that, but this doesnt solve my problem. I just uploaded the x86 built to web-server, there was no problem. The problem is when i built the application in x64. Then i get the error